# Brand / Supplier of this capacitor

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

Having trouble to identify this capacitor, not for its values but its specifics. They're all being used in the AKAI reference series. This particular photo was taken from the power supply board of the AKAI AT 93L.

[image]

Comment: I see the logo of Nippon Chemi-Con: http://www.chemi-con.co.jp/e/

Comment: Service manual says AS1 type, shown as AS-I on the capacitor. Given the age of the device, no such capacitor type was found any more, or it's a custom for Akai so there are no public specs.

Comment: These are aluminium electrolytic capacitors, radial, snap-in mount. Likely of some audio family of caps. Chances are that this is a pre-RoHS part that's no longer listed on their site (Japan was even earlier than Europe with Pb free). I think you have to contact Nippon Chemi-Con and ask. They will have a replacement but probably with a different part number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a symbol shown on each of the caps that looks like some sort of badge:

[image]

This is the symbol for [Nippon Chemi-Con](http://www.chemi-con.co.jp/e/), which is a company that makes high-quality capacitors:

[image]

Comment: Well, that's something I never would've noticed, thanks !!

Comment: You get used to it over time!